# Error while starting the Hadoop using start-all.sh

Tags: hadoop

While starting the Hadoop using strat-all.sh, the following error is coming:

```
2012-06-28 19:51:56,655 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Does not contain a valid host:port authority: localhost:54311 
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:128)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.getAddress(JobTracker.java:2560)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.<init>(JobTracker.java:2200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.<init>(JobTracker.java:2192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.<init>(JobTracker.java:2186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.startTracker(JobTracker.java:300)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.startTracker(JobTracker.java:291)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.main(JobTracker.java:4978)

2012-06-28 19:51:56,655 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

### mapred-site.xml content

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>localhost:54311 </value>
    <description>mapred</description>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

### System configuration

```
RHEL V5.0 enterprise
JDK : java 1.6.0_26
Hadoop : 1.0.3
```

Comment: Silly observation, but is the space after the port number a typo? It shouldn't matter anyway, but worth a try.

Comment: and do let us know if removing the space worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Verify your cluster configuration. Specifically the /etc/hosts file. Verify the name given to your name node.

Is your name node and job tracker running on same machine ?